# AG grid react enterprise version server side feature

Tags: reactjs, ag-grid

I am using `ag-grid` enterprise version 29.1 in my `react` project. I am using pagination and filter where I am calling backend API for both. Now I want to implement the use case in the data grid user will select the particular row and click on the delete button.

Below is my **delete code**:-

```
const handleDeleteEmployee = () => {
    const selectedEmployee = employeeDataGrid.current?.api?.getSelectedRows();
    const transaction = { remove: [selectedEmployee[0]] };
    const data = testRef.current.api.applyServerSideTransaction(transaction)
}
```

my **onGridReddy**:-

```
const onGridReady = (params) => {
    employeeDataGrid.current = params.api;
    const source = getEmployeeDataSource()
    params.api.setServerSideDatasource(source);
};
```

**getEmployeeDataSrocue**:-

```
const getEmployeeDataSrocue = () => {
    return {
        async getRows(params) {
            const response = await getDetails(
                params.request.startRow,
                Object.keys(employeeDataGrid.current.api.getFilterModel());
            params.successCallback(response?.data?.details,
            );
        },
    };
};
```

Issue:-
When HandleDelete is called row is correctly getting deleted in datagrid on the client side but the `getRows` function gets called which call api again.
has anyone faced the same issue

Expectation:-
after doing applyServerSideTransaction getRows should not get called``]`